# When approximating the value of pi with the leibniz formula

Tags: python-3.x

My question is: Why do these two programs provide different answers! Thank you in advance!
I created two programs that find the value of pi as close as possible based off of the user input for the total sum. However, I created two programs one that steps by 2 and one that steps by 4. I was wondering why the answers provided by the two codes are different.
Code that uses 2 step.

```
import math
total = 0
def main():
    #input
    n = int(input("How many numbers are we going to process: "))

    #process
    #initialize total
    total = 0
    #create the loop that runs via amount input
    for i in range(0, n , 2):
        total = total + ( 1 / ((i * 2) + 1)) - (1 / ((i * 2) + 3))

    amount = total * 4

    print(amount)
    print("In comparison to pi the value is: ", (math.pi - amount))
main()
```

Code that uses 4 step

```
    import math
    total = 0
    def main():
        #input
        n = int(input("How many numbers are we going to process: "))

        #process
        #initialize total
        total = 0
        #create the loop that runs via amount input
        for i in range(0, n , 4):
            total = total + ( 1 / ((i * 2) + 1)) - (1 / ((i * 2) + 3)) + (1/ 
((i * 2) + 5)) - (1/ ((i * 2) + 7))

        amount = total * 4

        print(amount)
        print("In comparison to pi the value is: ", (math.pi - amount))
    main()
```

Comment: In your current code: You are applying 2 different formulas  supplying different parameters.
it appears that you are not using recursive programming properly and  You are not use the range() function correctly

Comment: @DaniDev I see, I'll look more into recursive programming. Thank you :D